# How do i display 'Store Contact Telephone'?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have set telephone number from admin panel 'Store Contact Telephone', Now i want to show this number in header, How do i achieve this?

Comment: get phone no. using Mage::getStoreConfig and place it in header.phtml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get store phone number using this

```
$storePhone = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
```

Comment: <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
$storePhone = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone');
echo $storePhone; 
?>  not working?

Answer (score 7):

In a template file, you add the telephone number by calling getStoreConfig like this…

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/phone'); ?>
```

If you need to include in a CMS Page,

```
{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}
```